# display data with ajax and json in oop php

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a coding like this, coding is a class that contains functions

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Ketidakpastian: Teorema Bayes</title>
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        body { 
            padding: 10 200 10 200;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".tooltipnya").tooltip({
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'right'
            });
        });

        $(function(){
            $("#form-hitung").submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"teorema-bayes.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        cacar = "<ol>";
                        $.each(data, function(i,n){
                            cacar = cacar + "<li>"+n["pesan"]+" : "+n["hasil"]+"</li>";
                        });
                        cacar = cacar + "</ol>";
                        $(".result-cacar").append(cacar);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    class TeoremaBayes {

        private $cacar;
        private $bintik2Cacar;
        private $bintik2TidakCacar;

        public function __construct($cacar, $bintik2Cacar, $bintik2TidakCacar) {
            $this->cacar = $cacar;
            $this->bintik2Cacar = $bintik2Cacar;
            $this->bintik2TidakCacar = $bintik2TidakCacar;
        }

        public function setCacar($probCacar) {
            $this->cacar = $probCacar;
        }

        public function getCacar() {
            return $this->cacar;
        }

        public function setBintik2Cacar($probBintik2Cacar) {
            $this->bintik2Cacar = $probBintik2Cacar;
        }

        public function getBintik2Cacar() {
            return $this->bintik2Cacar;
        }

        public function setBintik2TidakCacar($probBintik2TidakCacar) {
            $this->bintik2TidakCacar = $probBintik2TidakCacar;
        }

        public function getBintik2TidakCacar() {
            return $this->bintik2TidakCacar;
        }

        //menghitung probabilitas tidak terkena cacar
        public function notCacar() {
            return $notCacar = 1 - $this->getCacar();
        }

        //menghitung prob. bintik2cacar kali prob. cacar
        public function hitungBintik2Cacar() {
            return $this->getBintik2Cacar() * $this->getCacar();
        }

        //menghitung prob. bintik2 tidak cacar kali prob. tidak cacar
        public function hitungBintik2TidakCacar() {
            return $this->getBintik2TidakCacar() * $this->notCacar();
        }

        //menghitung prob. terkena cacar
        public function terkenaCacar() {
            return round($this->hitungBintik2Cacar() / ($this->hitungBintik2Cacar() + $this->hitungBintik2TidakCacar()), 2);
        }

        //menghitung prob. tidak terkena cacar
        public function tidakTerkenaCacar() {
            return round($this->hitungBintik2TidakCacar() / ($this->hitungBintik2TidakCacar() + $this->hitungBintik2Cacar()), 2);
        }

        public function inputUser() {
            ?>
            <h3>Ketidakpastian: Teorema Bayes</h3>
            <p style="font-size: 16px">Menghitung Probabilitas seseorang terkena penyakit cacar atau tidak</p>
            <form action="" method="post" id="form-hitung">

                <table class="table" style="font-size: 16px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Probabilitas cacar</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="probCacar" class="tooltipnya" style="height: 30px; width: 50px; text-align: right;" rel="tooltip" title="Masukkan peluang, misal 0.3"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Probabilitas munculnya bintik-bintik diwajah maka cacar</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="probBintik2Cacar" class="tooltipnya" style="height: 30px; width: 50px; text-align: right;" rel="tooltip" title="Masukkan peluang, misal 0.3"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Probabilitas munculnya bintik-bintik diwajah maka tidak cacar</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="probBintik2TidakCacar" class="tooltipnya" style="height: 30px; width: 50px; text-align: right;" rel="tooltip" title="Masukkan peluang, misal 0.3"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
            <?php
        }

        public function dataJson() {
            $data1 = array("pesan" => "Probabilitas tidak terkena cacar", "hasil" => $this->notCacar());
            $data2 = array("pesan" => "Probabilitas terkena cacar jika ada bintik-bintik merah diwajah", "hasil" => $this->terkenaCacar());
            $data3 = array("pesan" => "Probabilitas tidak terkena cacar jika ada bintik-bintik merah diwajah", "hasil" => $this->tidakTerkenaCacar());
            $gabungData = array($data1, $data2, $data3);
        }

        public function tampilHasil() {
            ?>
            <div class="result-cacar">

            </div>
            <?php
        }

    }
    ?>
</body>
```

then I create an object to call a function from a class that has been made

```
<?php

require_once 'teorema-bayes.php';
$cacar = new TeoremaBayes($_POST['probCacar'], $_POST['probBintik2Cacar'],          $_POST['probBintik2TidakCacar']);
$cacar->inputUser();
echo json_decode($cacar->dataJson());
$cacar->tampilHasil();
?>
```

but to call the results of the data can not, is there something wrong in his ajax and json?

please help me

Comment: OOP in spaghetti code?  really?  Maybe think about putting your class in it's own file and including it. And then maybe get all the display logic out of your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_decode($cacar->dataJson());
```

Shouldn't that be json_encode:

```
echo json_encode($cacar->dataJson());
```

If I'm reading your example correctly that should be it. Though I don't know what this does:

```
$cacar->tampilHasil();
```

EDIT:

Ooooh... I see now. Get rid of `$cacar->tampilHasil();` in your response method. since all it does is output some empty div. That will mess up your json results.

... and wait... You're echoing out a form in `$cacar->inputUser();`? You have a lot of clean up to do here. This thing's a mess.

The basic idea is that you're expecting json data as a result and you're serving all kinds of html mixed in with it. Your result method should ONLY return an array json encoded. Nothing more or it WILL fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying you just read JSON in your AJAX call, you need to actually out JSON using

```
echo json_encode($cacar->dataJson());
```

You then need to remove the `$cacar->tampilHasil()` from your output as that is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

First off the reason you are not seeing data (which is what I think you are trying to say) is that you are trying to pass $_POST data that has not yet been submitted into the constructor of the Class. Those $_POST array variables will not be present unless a user submits them, and it looks like you have the HTML form you currently have jumbled into your inputUser() method which is called after the Constructor (naturally).

Furthermore, this is NOT good OOP. You seem to have a read a bit online and then started typing. You need to separate the Class logic of what you're trying to do with the data from the display logic (i.e. HTML & HTML generation). Start by looking at some PHP frameworks or just general OOP guidance.